# Dropping duplicate rows ignoring case (lowercase or Uppercase)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with one column (col). I'm trying to remove duplicate records regardless of lowercase or Uppercase, for example

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['Appliance Identification', 'Natural Language','Social networks',
                                  'natural language', 'Personal robot', 'Social Networks', 'Natural language']})
```

output:

```
Col
0   Appliance Identification
1   Natural Language
2   Social networks
3   natural language
4   Personal robot
5   Social Networks
6   Natural language
```

Expected Output:

```
Col
0   Appliance Identification
1   Social networks
2   Personal robot
3   Natural language
```

How can this Dropping be done regardless of case-insensitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
df.groupby(df['Col'].str.lower(), as_index=False, sort=False).first()
```

output:

```
                        Col
0  Appliance Identification
1          Natural Language
2           Social networks
3            Personal robot
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert values to lowercase and filter duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with invert mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['Col'].str.lower().duplicated()]
print (df)
                        Col
0  Appliance Identification
1          Natural Language
2           Social networks
4            Personal robot
```